# pyspark jdbc dataframe creation using LDAP connections from Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create pyspark jdbc dataframe using LDAP connections from Oracle.

Below code is working for normal connection string based JDBC dataframe creation which worked.

```
creds = {"user":"USER_NAME",
             "password":"PASSWORD",
             "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"}


connection_string = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.com:1521/myint.domain.com"

df = spark_session.read.jdbc(url=connection_string, table=query, properties=creds)
```

Now, our database configurations changed and we are supposed to use LDAP based authentication only.

Hence I tried changing `connection_string` as below.

```
connection_string  = "myint"
```

But, it is throwing below issue.

**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.jdbc.
: java.lang.NullPointerException**

Without Spark, I tried connecting using `cx_Oracle` module(python module for connecting to Oracle) for testing and it worked.

Before:

```
host = 'myint.domain.com'
ip = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.com'
port = 1521
conn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=host)

db = cx_Oracle.connect('USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD', conn)  # giving the conn object
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from myschema.mytable fetch first 5 rows only""")

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

After:

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD', "myint")  # Now, just giving only the database
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from myschema.mytable fetch first 5 rows only""")

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

I need to achieve the same in Pyspark JDBC dataframe by just passing only the database name. Please suggest what needs to be done.

I hope this question can be applicable for scala spark as well.